# Pandas: converting timestamp into datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column of date time strings in `UTC` which I need to convert to a viable datetime format in `EST` using `pandas`. I successfully converted the column, however I feel that my solution is long-winded and can be simplified, but I'm not sure how. Here is the way I'm currently converting the dates:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=5)
```

Here are a few sample of the original string format:

```
2014-02-07T00:25:40Z
2014-02-07T00:25:40Z
2014-02-07T00:25:41Z
2014-02-07T00:25:42Z
2014-02-07T00:25:42Z
2014-02-07T00:25:43Z
2014-02-07T00:25:43Z
2014-02-07T00:25:44Z
2014-02-07T00:25:44Z    
2014-02-07T00:25:44Z
```

Can I convert this column with one or two lines? I tried performing the `Timedelta()` in the same step as the datetime formatting but received an error. Alternately I tried using `tz_convert()` and `tz_localize()` but received error with `tz_convert()` saying that my datetime wasn't a viable datetime format (hence why I reset the column to datetime after formatting). With `tz_localize()` it just added `-5:00` to the end of my datetime instead of actually subtracting the 5 hours from the `UTC` time.

This is how the output should look:

```
2014-02-06 19:25:40
2014-02-06 19:25:40
2014-02-06 19:25:41
2014-02-06 19:25:42
2014-02-06 19:25:42
2014-02-06 19:25:43
2014-02-06 19:25:43
2014-02-06 19:25:44
2014-02-06 19:25:44
2014-02-06 19:25:44
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do `tz_localize` and `tz_localize`

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.tz_localize('UTC').\
     dt.tz_convert('EST').\
      dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
0    2014-02-06 19:25:40
1    2014-02-06 19:25:41
2    2014-02-06 19:25:42
3    2014-02-06 19:25:42
4    2014-02-06 19:25:43
5    2014-02-06 19:25:43
6    2014-02-06 19:25:44
7    2014-02-06 19:25:44
8    2014-02-06 19:25:44
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: I received a `TypeError: Already tz-aware, use tz_convert to convert.`

Comment: @andrrvt15 I am just using your input data and this is working fine on my side

Comment: @andrrvt15 https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/issues/671, try to update your pandas

Comment: I removed `dt.tz_localize()` and it looks to have worked!